Why does touching the + terminal of a battery not shock you but the phase of an outlet does?
I have a problem with understanding electricity.
My understanding was that electricity "wants" to go from the positive to the negative side and the current depends on the voltage.
So considering that it makes sense that I don't get shocked when touching the positive terminal of a battery because the current cannot flow to the negative side and therefore does not flow through my body.
For some reason I would however get shocked when I were to touch only the phase of an outlet and I can't understand why. I've read that the current flows through the ground back to the origin. But then I am still wondering why wearing rubber shoes would make a difference in the grand scheme of things where the power would need to flow through my body and all floors of my building and several miles to a substation.
On top of that If the power can do all that while flowing through my body, why does my body make that big of a difference and it won't just flow through the sides of the outlet and through the walls?

It sounds like you need a deeper understanding of what electricity is. This might help - What is Electricity?

The phase of the outlet can shock you because the other source terminal (the neutral of the outlet) is connected to earth. This may be a galvanic connection but there is definitely a capacitive connection in the (large) transformers that are present in the network, and from long lines to ground. So if your feet have a low resistance to earth, there can be a closed current path through earth, back to the the neutral, through the source to the phase of the outlet and back to you!
Usually your feet will have a large resistance to ground (due to the soles of the shoes and the floor material) so in many cases you won't feel anything or only a very small tingling, when touching the phase (but the risk is there, you cannot be sure!) Much riskier is to touch the phase and with the other hand touch the neutral, which gives a guaranteed path through your body without extra resistance. You will then certainly feel the shock. And if you hold on a few seconds you'll still have muscle soreness the next day. And you can even die if it accidentally comes at the critical point between heart beats and only one half of the heart feels it strong enough to react to it, which sends your heart in fibrillation due to different parts being out of sync! (If it's strong enough to reset the whole heart then it might be OK, although there will then still be the risk that you can't let loose! The outlet voltage will not easily burn your entire body, that would require many thousands of Volts.)
Note that all this can also occur if you touch a battery terminal and the other battery terminal is connected to earth. With modern electric car batteries and home storage batteries, this might be the case. And the voltage can be even higher than that of the mains outlet.
Note also that this can not happen if the neutral has no connection to ground, e.g. when there is a small isolation transformer (keeping the neutral isolated from ground and without significant capacitive coupling to ground). For instance with a "shaving transformer", see picture:


The key here is to ask, "where is the voltage potential, and how many volts is it?"
What is a voltage potential? If you take a multimeter, and touch two points, it will tell you how many volts there are across that gap.
A multimeter that touches the red and black on a car battery will read 12 ish volts. Touching the red terminal to a random metal pole will read next to nothing. There is no legitimate path between the two for electrons to be interested in hoping around. The voltage potential exists because of the battery chemistry and it has little interest to explore
Low voltage is tame because everything is an insulator, even the human body. Touching a car battery doesn't do anything because 12V isn't enough to overcome all the resistance across those terminals (your body). That is the only reason why you don't get shocked. If you put a bunch of batteries in series and make the voltage much higher, you will get shocked.
Power distribution is a whole different animal... There is not inherent "electricity goes from one terminal to the other" as this is alternating current from the grid. The electricity that comes out of your outlet is NOT from a battery, and it is much higher. 10 times higher. 120V. There are two important things here.

The voltage potential is now high enough for it to not really mind the resistance your body offers. It views you as an inefficient conductor.

The multimeter exercise is now much different. It's not just 120V measured from line to neutral, it is 120V from line to ground...



But then I am still wondering why wearing rubber shoes would make a
difference in the grand scheme of things where the power would need to
flow through my body and all floors of my building and several miles
to a substation.

So yes, wearing rubber boots makes a difference if you get shocked by grazing an active line, because the boots contribute to resistance going back to ground. As you get shocked, the current is not going miles and miles back to the substation, but rather flowing through the buildings metal, and back to the ground of the transformer that feeds the building you talking about. That transformer is surely grounded to the building itself. It's a very clean path as far as the electricity is concerned which is why you will get ZAPPED.
Boots to not help you if you chose to grab line and neutral at the same time as it will flow through your arms.

On top of that If the power can do all that while flowing through my
body, why does my body make that big of a difference and it won't just
flow through the sides of the outlet and through the walls?

The insulating material used in all electrical hardware offers much, much higher resistance then your body. 120V looks at that like an impenetrable wall. But all you have to do is make the voltage higher and higher, and things that used to be an insulator are now a conductor.
I've included an example of power distribution architecture for your convenience.
https://www.electrical-contractor.net/forums/ubbthreads.php/ubb/printthread/Board/5/main/19299/type/thread.html



I would however get shocked when I were to touch only the phase of an outlet.

Not a complete answer here, but there is one detail that other answers don't mention. Even if you are completely insulated from Earth, you still can feel a tingle when you touch a "hot" wire (a.k.a., a "phase") because your body effectively still is connected to Earth by a small capacitance. The voltage between the hot wire and Earth is alternating. It changes sign 50 or 60 times* per second. With each half-cycle of the waveform, a burst of current rushes into or out from your body, to keep the voltage between your body and Earth equal to the voltage between the hot wire and Earth. The current is very small (as compared to the potentially lethal current you would feel if your bare feet were standing on wet ground) but it still is enough for you to feel it.
You don't feel the same tingle if you touch a neutral conductor because what defines a "neutral" is that it is directly connected to Earth at various points in the distribution network. Assuming that there are no faults in the wiring, the voltage between neutral and Earth always will be zero.†

* Power line frequency depends on what part of the world you live in.
† Or, very close to zero. It can be somewhat different from zero if the neutral conductor that you touch supplies some appliance that is drawing heavy current, but it still will be *much* less than the voltage between the hot wire and Earth.
